# How to make web form appear after previous web form has data entered into it?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby, sinatra, slim-lang

I'm looking to make a second web form appear after the first web form has something entered into it. I'm currently using a sinatra set up with slim as the templating engine, and pure javascript.

```
input#topic value="Enter topic" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='Enter topic'?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Enter topic':this.value;"

input#subtopic value="Enter subtopic" onfocus="this.value = this.value=='Enter subtopic?'':this.value;" onblur="this.value = this.value==''?'Enter subtopic':this.value;"
```

The above are my two forms, the onfocus and onblur are to make the form value disappear and reappear if clicked on.

My javascript is as follows.

```
function checkField(field) {
    if(field.value != null) {
        document.getElementById('subtopic_form').style.display = 'true';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('subtopic_form').style.display = 'false';
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, and part of the problem is that when I add to the input tags

```
onchange="checkField(this)"
```

then I get a function unused message inside my javascript file, even though I have specified in my home.slim file

```
script src="/js/application.js"
```

Any help to get this to work as I need is much appreciated.
I'm open to using jquery for this, and if there was any way to make the second form have an effect upon appearance that'd be awesome.

-Adam

Answer (score 0):

The display property accepts several values, but true and false are not among them. To get a full list, go to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) or [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530751%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). But I can tell you right now, that the values you most likely want are "none" and "block", as in:

```
function checkField(field) {
    if(field.value != null && field.value != '') {
        document.getElementById('subtopic_form').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('subtopic_form').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

with jQuery, though, this code could be quite a bit cleaner!

```
function checkField(field) {
    if (field.value != null && field.value != '') {
        $("#subtopic_form").show();
    } else {
        $("#subtopic_form").hide();
    }
}
```

or even

```
$("#topic").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val()) {
        $("#subtopic_form").show();
    } else {
        $("#subtopic_form").hide();
    }
});
```

and if you want effects, consider jQuery's [.fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) or [.slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) in place of .hide()

Note that I added field.value != ''  to your code. Also, it would be best to use !== instead of !=.

:)